# How to get correct typing on a type union with a property that can be either a specific word or any given string

Tags: typescript

I have an object that can be two types. The type of the object depends on the property `type`. `type` can be any string but if `type === "specific string"` then the object type will be different, like so:

```
interface Input {
  type: string;
  value: any;
}

interface Checkbox {
  type: "checkbox";
  checked: boolean;
}

type EventUnion = Checkbox | Input;
```

But when I try to do:

```
function handleEvent(event: EventUnion) {
  if (event.type === "checkbox") {
    console.log(event.checked); // Property 'checked' does not exist
  }
};
```

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that according to the `Input` interface, the `type` property may well be `"checkbox"`.  TypeScript doesn't have [negated types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317) (as of TS3.5 anyway), so there's no way to specify something like `string & not "checkbox"`.

Therefore, if `event.type === "checkbox"`, you still can't be sure that `event` is a `CheckBox` and not an `Input`.  TypeScript doesn't even understand the inverse check where `event.type !== "checkbox"` implies that `event` is an `Input`.  TypeScript really only does control-flow based narrowing of union types if you are checking a discriminant property of a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions). Discriminant properties must be single-value types, so checking a property of type `string` just does not act as a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types).

---

One way to deal with this is to change how you are discriminating between union members.  For example, check for the presence of a property which is only known to exist on one of the members of the union.  This type of check has been supported [since TypeScript 2.7](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#type-guards-inferred-from--in-operator):

```
function handleEvent(event: EventUnion) {
  if ("checked" in event) {
    console.log(event.checked); // okay
  } else {
    console.log(event.value); // okay
  }
}
```

The presence of `"checked"` narrows `event` to `CheckBox`, and the absence narrows `event` to `Input`.  This of course means that you don't even need the `type` property to distinguish between `CheckBox` and `Input`.

---

If you want to keep checking the `type` property, you can communicate that this check should be a type guard by making [your own type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```
function eventIsCheckBox(event: EventUnion): event is Checkbox {
    return event.type === "checkbox";
}
```

The return type of `eventIsCheckbox(event)` is `event is Checkbox`, a type predicate that tells the compiler that a `true` result means `event` is a `Checkbox`, and that a `false` result means `event` is *not* a `Checkbox`.  This doesn't follow directly from the definition of the `Input` and `Checkbox` interfaces; rather, this function is your way of asserting to the compiler that such a check is valid.  Let's use it:

```
function handleEvent2(event: EventUnion) {
  if (eventIsCheckBox(event)) {
    console.log(event.checked); // okay
  } else {
    console.log(event.value); // okay
  }
}
```

The same check happens at runtime as in your original code, but now the compiler will accept that it determines whether or not `event` is a `CheckBox`.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIgA4FczIN4CwAUMsmAJ4YQBcyAzmFKAOYDcxpAbnADZY3I4IcuyIBfYsVCRYiFAGEAFhAQBrAEYB7AB74OZSgIBECZWq3ajo0qZWqIAE1pbNPCENESixClWQBRTghwAFUQYE0QZABeZCU7C2QAHzRMHFFiGCwQBDAIqMUhBzdA4LAACggg8FpS0PDIgEo9EmRgGGRykzN7ByM2qKqy5sJWm0i6VwgAOh5NZkrqsGnbNUdG1mQAei3kTVU4cn0xZAgeOhRR0nGQSbdZ+cWy6e4+CA3t3f3D4+IvTOyuXypyWqDo8TUACEdE8agElmF8o1aENwG06HEeokrtcoBAwFgoIMltNfChohTkN0EjorH9JEQsjk8pFkIUQMUIHUwAAmWFgWoIhogEb6dqdVFgMEQ1TQ7T8xqisbIBATKYPBaSlY9dabHZ7A5HVonM4XFrXFVq+5zTUk178D7675G0hef5EIA)